# How to retrieve a Facebook O-Auth session from Python Flask

Tags: python, facebook, session, authentication, flask

So I'm going through the auth-o-matic flask tutorial. I was able to get it to work but now I want to of course apply the session to my other pages. If a user has logged in they will have a session specific to the browser. The tutorial recommended If I wanted to use flask-session to save the session in this way.

```
result = authomatic.login(
   WerkzeugAdapter(request, response),
   provider_name,
   session=session,
   session_saver=lambda: app.save_session(session, response)
)
```

When looking at examples like (runnable.com/Uhf58hcCo9RSAACs/using-sessions-in-flask-for-python) this using flask sessions I notice that the session is bound more explicitly to `app.session`. Which makes sense that I can then check the session in an if statement every time a user requests a route. 
I imagine something like,

```
@app.route('/content')
def content():
    if app.open_session(app):
        return render_template('content.html', session=app.open_session() )
    return render_template('content.html')
```

This makes sense to me so I'm wondering if it's coming from a misunderstanding of sessions. If anyone can explain this small example for me of explain why it doesn't work I would really appreciate it! I've posted the full code on a GitHub gist (link below).

TLDR: I have a facebook authentication from auth-o-matic and I can't access the session variable to apply it to my other routes to make sure a user is logged in when accessing critical sections. Code examples and full code in links.

Thank You!

https://gist.github.com/DavidAwad/f881a6ec64e8e2be2b86